# function that returns first object of a given array

Tags: javascript

```
function first(array){ 
return first(0);    
var first = ["gold","brown","green"21,1998];
    console.log(first[0]);
```

trying to create a function that will return the first object of a given array, and am getting an error self[e.data.invoke.func].apply is not a function
not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: can you post the function you've done so far?

Comment: That error seems completely unrelated.

Comment: function first(array){
  return first(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked

```
function firstObject(array){
     return array[0];
}

var first = ["Weresquirrel", "Werebear", "Werepanda", "Weremonkey"];

console.log(firstObject(first));
```

Comment: so I was missing the ; after my return array

Comment: From your comment, you are calling your array in the function, with a wrong way to call the first element (`[]`, not `()` brackets), and you didn't close the function body `}`. You want your function to be generic. So that you can put any array in it. If you've defined your function `function first(first){ return first[0]; }`, you'd might have a working function (but it's better not to have the function, it's argument and the existing array be named the same)...